# How to open Android tab in Intellij IDEA 12 from keyboard?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

*I'm jump to IDEA 12 from Eclipse 6 month ago and fist of all I want to say a big thank to all developers from JetBrains.*

I like to use IDEA in full screen mode, how I can open Android tool-tab from keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open IDEA's preferences
2. Go to IDE Settings > Keymap in the tree
3. Type 'android' in the search field to find Main Menu > View > Tool Windows > Android
4. Right-click or double-click to add a keyboard shortcut of your choice